# Why is XAML not the equivalent of AddHandler?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I am porting over a WPF application to Windows Universal. I want to add the same MouseLeftButtonDown handlers to my controls. They seem to have been replaced with the Tapped Event. However, when I add a handler as such:

```
<Border Tapped="brd_Tapped" />
```

The handler is not called. After researching the common suggestion is to set the AddHandler in codebehind like this:

```
            Brd1.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(Brd_Tapped), true);
```

This works but when I have dynamically generated items like a ListViewItem this becomes more complicated.

Why doesn't the XAML handler do the same as the AddHandler in codebehind, like in WPF?

Comment: Hmm, no, that works just fine.  Maybe you like PointerPressed better.  Sounds like you are using the beta version of VS2015 so always non-zero odds for random trouble.  Use connect.microsoft.com to report bugs.

Comment: @Hans: can you tell me in what software you saw this was working? I can currently only open this project in the VS2015 RC. So you suggest this is a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other control inside the border has probably handled the Tapped event before it gets to your Border. [AddHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler.aspx)(routedEvent,eventHandler,**true**) is specifically designed for scenarios where you want to get the event even if it has already been handled by somebody else.

AddHandler's behavior is not the default since it is generally not a good idea to handle an already handled event. AddHandler is an option for those cases where it is needed.

Which event to replace MouseLeftButtonDown with depends on the specific usage. PointerPressed is a slightly closer analogue than the higher level Tapped event. Which to use (if either) depends on what you're trying to do. Either way you'll want to make sure there is some way to get to the behavior without touch/mouse. In many cases you'll be better off using a styled Button to get full Click semantics rather than handling the pointer or Tapped events directly.